# What after download Ubuntu on windows 8

Tags: software-installation, windows-8

So I've got some problems while downloading Ubuntu.

As I clicked on the downloadlink ( the first one you see when you get on the destkop page), the Ubuntu link started downloading.  When it was downloaded the problems started because I don't know which further stap I need to take since the download program mentions things like DVD and I didn't get a DVD from Ubuntu I just got the downloaded software!

Which steps do you need to take after you've downloaded Ubuntu?

---

What do I need to do when I dowloaded the software?  Can anyone explain it in steps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [installation instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop) are right under the download link. You should burn the DVD yourself or create a pendrive. Depending on which browser you're using and how you configured it the file got saved somewhere and you can open it with you DVD bruning application (or consider creating an USB pendrive as described in the installation guide). Additionally your browser might already open the downloaded file with the burning application or with a nonsense application.

Comment: Thank you! So I'll need to copy past the software on an USB-stick or DVD?

Comment: For a USB stick, you need to use special software to 'burn' the .ISO to the stick, like UNetBootin.

Comment: @EvaVandenberghe "So I'll need to copy past the software on an USB-stick or DVD?" -> did you read the installation instructions (and the linked instructions to verify you burned the iso correctly) at all?